# How to get Heart Rate from Mi Band using Bluetooth Le

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, heartrate

I want to get the Heart Rate through BluetoothLe from my Mi Band 2. I tried to follow the example from `Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy` but I didn't succeed to write the value from Heart Rate. I think I miss something but I cannot realize what. It's the first time I am working with bluetooth and smart band. I wish you could help me. I do not know if for starting the Heart Rate sensor should I use as `{0x01} byte`.

So following the example I downloaded the BluetoothLeDemo app and I got from there `BleWrapper` `BleDefinedUUIDs` and `BleNamesResolver`. I have 2 buttons Scan and stop. I created a BleWrapper, called mBleWrapper to use it for starting scanning and stop scanning.

```java
mBleWrapper = new BleWrapper(this, new BleWrapperUiCallbacks.Null(){


            @Override
            public void uiDeviceConnected(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device) {
                super.uiDeviceConnected(gatt, device);
            }

            @Override
            public void uiDeviceDisconnected(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device) {
                super.uiDeviceDisconnected(gatt, device);
            }

            @Override
            public void uiAvailableServices(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, List<BluetoothGattService> services) {
                super.uiAvailableServices(gatt, device, services);

                BluetoothGattCharacteristic c=null;

                for(BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                    String serviceName = BleNamesResolver.resolveUuid(service.getUuid().toString());
                    Log.i("SERVIDE", serviceName);
                    }
                }
c=gatt.getService(BleDefinedUUIDs.Service.HEART_RATE).getCharacteristic(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
                mBleWrapper.writeDataToCharacteristic(c, new byte[]{0x01});
                mState = mSensorState.ACC_ENABLE;

            }

            @Override
            public void uiCharacteristicForService(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothGattService service, List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> chars) {
                super.uiCharacteristicForService(gatt, device, service, chars);

            }

            @Override
            public void uiCharacteristicsDetails(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothGattService service, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                super.uiCharacteristicsDetails(gatt, device, service, characteristic);
            }

            @Override
            public void uiNewValueForCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothGattService service, BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, String strValue, int intValue, byte[] rawValue, String timestamp) {
                super.uiNewValueForCharacteristic(gatt, device, service, ch, strValue, intValue, rawValue, timestamp);
                switch (mState) {
                    case ACC_READ:
                        Log.i("READ", "heart rate dta");
                }

                    Log.i("Value", "Val" + intValue);

            }

            @Override
            public void uiGotNotification(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothGattService service, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
                super.uiGotNotification(gatt, device, service, characteristic);
                String ch = BleNamesResolver.resolveCharacteristicName(characteristic.getUuid().toString());

                Log.d("AAA",  "uiGotNotification: " + ch);
            }

            @Override
            public void uiSuccessfulWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothGattService service, BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, String description) {
                super.uiSuccessfulWrite(gatt, device, service, ch, description);
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic c;
                switch (mState) {
                    case ACC_ENABLE:
                        Log.i("ENABLED", "Heart Rate enabled");
                        c = gatt.getService(BleDefinedUUIDs.Service.HEART_RATE).getCharacteristic(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
                        mBleWrapper.requestCharacteristicValue(c);
                        mState = mSensorState.ACC_READ;
                        break;
                    case ACC_READ:
                        Log.i("WRITE", "SUCCESSfule write");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void uiFailedWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, BluetoothGattService service, BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, String description) {
                super.uiFailedWrite(gatt, device, service, ch, description);
                switch (mState) {
                    case ACC_ENABLE:
                        Log.i("FAILED", "Feailed to enbale Heart Rate");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void uiNewRssiAvailable(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
                super.uiNewRssiAvailable(gatt, device, rssi);
            }

            @Override
            public void uiDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] record) {
                super.uiDeviceFound(device, rssi, record);
                String msg = "uiDeviceFound: "+device.getAddress()+","+device.getName();
                if(devicesList.contains(device)==false) {
                    Log.i("Devicce", "deviceFound: " + msg);
                    devicesList.add(device);
                    genericListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });
```

I display all devices found with a `ListView` and `onClick` I want to connect to that item and write the Heart Rate in the Log.

```java
 deviceListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             BluetoothGatt gatt;
             BluetoothGattCharacteristic c;
             connectDevice((BluetoothDevice) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

             Log.i("Read", "Get Heart Rate");
             if(mBleWrapper.isConnected()==false){
                Log.i("not connected", "NOT CONNECTE");
                 return;
             }

             gatt = mBleWrapper.getGatt();
             c = gatt.getService(BleDefinedUUIDs.Service.HEART_RATE).getCharacteristic(BleDefinedUUIDs.Characteristic.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
             mBleWrapper.requestCharacteristicValue(c);
             mState=mSensorState.ACC_READ;


            }
        });
```

I also added at BleWrapper class `onDescpritorWriter`

```java
 @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);

            String deviceName = gatt.getDevice().getName();
            String serviceName = BleNamesResolver.resolveServiceName(descriptor.getCharacteristic().getService().getUuid().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
            String charName = BleNamesResolver.resolveCharacteristicName(descriptor.getCharacteristic().getUuid().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
            String description = "Device: " + deviceName + " Service: " + serviceName + " Characteristic: " + charName;

            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                mUiCallback.uiSuccessfulWrite(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, mBluetoothSelectedService, descriptor.getCharacteristic(), description);
            }
            else {
                mUiCallback.uiFailedWrite(mBluetoothGatt, mBluetoothDevice, mBluetoothSelectedService, descriptor.getCharacteristic(), description + " STATUS = " + status);
            }

        }
```

And for UUIDS for service I used

```
UUID HEART_RATE = UUID.fromString("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

and for Charachteristics

```
UUID HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT   = UUID.fromString("00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

In other examples I saw that they also used the UUIDS for descriptor, but me not. I know that is a long post and question, but please I really need some help.

Comment: The MiBand 2 requires authentication: see [How I hacked my Xiaomi MiBand 2 fitness tracker](https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/how-i-hacked-xiaomi-miband-2-to-control-it-from-linux-a5bd2f36d3ad) or [Mi Band 2, Part 1: Authentication](https://leojrfs.github.io/writing/miband2-part1-auth/).

Answer (score 1):

There are something you can check around.

Obviously, you have successfully discovered devices around. According to [this](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/)(Bluetooth official document) heart rate service (UUID:180d) need set notify to TRUE first. Something like:

1. Use UUID:00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb to get the descriptor of the characteristic.

```
 BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(Client_Characteristic_Configuration);
```

2. Set the feature (Notify) of descriptor to TRUE:

```
 descriptor.setValue((BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE));
```

3. Write the value to the BLE device (using Gatt object from the callback function)

```
gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

After above, you may get the data in override function:

```
public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status)
```

By this way:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic Char = gatt.getService(FORA_SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(The uuid you want to connect);

byte[] data = Char.getValue();
```

And maybe you can show the example link. It can be more clear what you had used.

Comment: Hi, the example is in the book, "Getting started with the Bluetooth LE". I tried this, but it is not working

Comment: Hi. 
Last time I going to get value from a device. However the device doesn't have "release" the service I need (cause the manufacturer customize their own service and package all data in it) 
The idea hit me that maybe you can use 
gatt.discoverService() to confirm whether the Mi band has the service you need.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it has the services for Heart Rate, I mean it discovers it

Comment: Hey @Mary I have recently worked on the same. I know Heart Rate service is available but i dont know how to access it. Did u got any solution?